# Trying to Install Tweepy using pip : Error "Can't load a json library"

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

When i go to my command line and run "pip install tweepy" I get this error

Python version 3.4.0

Any ideas?

[image: Command Line output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error while trying to load a JSON library, but rather a Python syntax error caused by differences between Python 2 and Python 3 that happens to occur on a `raise` line. See the two lines that follow the `raise` line:

```
raise ImportError, "Can't load a json library"
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Tweepy [only supports Python 2](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy#installation):

> **Note** only Python 2.6 and 2.7 are supported at the moment. The Python 3 family is not yet supported.

If you intend to work with Twitter using Python 3, I invite you to review [this list](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#python) of libraries from the Twitter developer site. In general, most libraries that support Python 3 will advertise that fact.